# Android GoogleMaps: How to change a Polyline's color to a transparent one?

Tags: android, polyline

So how could I change my **polyline's actual color to a transparent version of it?**

There's **no setAlpha() or alpha() function for polyline** just like for a Marker.
So I tought I could simple ask the color of the polyline, make it transparent then re-set the new color.

If I use **getColor()** on polyline I get ints like this:

```
-4540819
```

I estimated some data like this: (So I could change the 'ff' values)

```
0xff222345 (for example)
```

[Because documetation says:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline)

> Line segment color in ARGB format, the same format used by Color. The
>   default value is black (0xff000000).

So how could I make this work?

Comment: Istant downvote in the very same minute as I posted the question. How I love this community.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet demonstrates how to make your polyline transparent. Just change `aa` to your desired transparency in hex.

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(90, -90))
    .color(0xaa222345);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298), new LatLng(-31.95285, 115.85734))
    .color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent_color)));
```

Where R.color.transparent_color is

```
<color name="transparent_color">#00000000</color>
```

In your resources.

Comment: I need to make transparent the actual color of the line.

Comment: It is makes it full transparent. Not the actual color's transparent version. (Partly transparent)